# How do you implement getters/setters in an interface?

Tags: inheritance, interface

I'm making a chess game, and I have a base 'piece' interface that I want all the pieces to implement. I have some common variables that each need to have, but I don't want to make getters and setters in each class (seems like it goes against DRY anyway).

What I've done is called my interface PieceBase, have a concrete class called Piece, and I have my actual pieces extent from Piece and implement PieceBase. I don't want Piece to ever be instantiated though, because it doesn't make sense by itself, and something about this method makes me uneasy.

How is this normally done?

Specifically, this is in Java, but I don't know if it's different in any other OO language.

Comment: Perhaps make an abstract instead of interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practice, at least in Java and C++, to use inheritance for the purpose of code reuse (see Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" for arguments).  It's typically better to use *composition* (or some other form of delegation) instead.

In your case I'd turn things around entirely, such that `Piece` is a `final class` simply taking an `enum` representing the type of piece it is:

```java
public final class Piece {

    public static enum Type {
        PAWN {
            List<Move> getLegalMoves(Color c, Location l) { /* ... */ }
        },
        BISHOP { /* ... */ },
        KNIGHT { /* ... */ },
        ROOK { /* ... */ },
        QUEEN { /* ... */ },
        KING { /* ... */ }; // i hope i didn't forget anything :P

        abstract List<Move> getLegalMoves(Color c, Location l);
        // ... etc.
    }

    private final Type type;
    private final Color color;
    private Location location;

    public Piece(Type type, Color color, Location location) {
        this.type = type;
        this.color = color;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public List<Move> getLegalMoves() {
        return type.getLegalMoves(color, location);
    }

    // ... etc.
}
```

So all of the logic common across all pieces is implemented once in `Piece`, and the differing portions are encapsulated by the `Type`.  And if you ever need to know what kind of piece you're looking at, you don't need to use `instanceof` and cast or anything, you just implement `Piece.getType()` and `switch` on that.

Comment: I agree that it is bad practice to use inheritance just for code re-use.  However this particular case seems like a text-book example of where it is appropriate to use inheritance: (A Bishop really "is-a" Piece and passing and calling an abstract getLegalMoves() on an abstract Piece is exactly what polymorphism is meant to be used for.)  For me, uses of a switch statement are a hint that there could be an alternative more object-oriented design.

Comment: Ah, but I *am* using inheritance!  Think of it this way: each value of `enum Type` is actually a *singleton instance* of an *anonymous* `final class` implementing `Type`'s interface.  These classes are used polymorphically in `Piece` (see `getLegalMoves()`).  Also note that this approach intentionally prevents additional `Piece` types from being defined by clients; in that sense it's akin to Scala's `sealed trait` combined with `case class`.

Comment: Very cool.  I do like this idiom for emulating `sealed trait`/`case class` in Java.  I probably will steal the idea and use it myself.  Thanks!  (Still, in this particular example I still would be inclined to use plain-old-inheritance of the Piece class.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird that you would want to extend Piece and Implement PieceBase... but maybe I'm not seeing something.   If you used an interface, all your classes that implement it will still have to define their own getters/setters.

It would seem to make sense to make an abstract class instead?

That way they all use the same getters/setters .... IF that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried with an abstract class, but I couldn't pass in Piece to a method. So for example

movePiece(Piece piece) only worked with an interface or a concrete class, but with an abstract class I would have to make 6 different methods for movePiece(Pawn pawn) movePiece(Rook rook)

Comment: That should work fine for an abstract class.  If you defined it as you said, movePiece(Piece piece) ... and instantiate your piece as Piece rook = new Rook();  , it should accept it fine.  Of course, I'm not sure WHY you would have Piece define your moving since each piece should have a different move function.

Comment: I'll give this a try. And this is to move from one place on the board to the another, the movement is handled separately in individual Piece instances

Comment: Tried this, it's giving me the same "Piece cannot be resolved to type" error. Eclipse suggestions are to create a class or an interface, so I don't think you can make references to abstract types.

Comment: That error usually refers to importing - did you import the abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I do not see the value of the interface.  I suggest simply defining the abstract class Piece with the required common getters and setters and then have your concrete classes extend Piece.

```
abstract class Piece { ... common stuff ...}
class Pawn extends Piece { ... pawn-specific stuff ... }
class Knight extends Piece { ... knight-specific stuff ... }
...
```

Comment: Please see my comment for dispake's answer, I believe I would run into the same issues

Comment: dispake's answer is basically the same as mine.

Comment: One question is why does your movePiece method of Piece take a Piece argument.  That implies two Pieces are involved: the "this" piece and the one passed in.

Comment: The movePiece example I gave was actually in my class Board, which needed to take in a Piece. But with an abstract class, it wouldn't accept it. I've used mergeconflict's example and have got it working.